# Why Bessel Function in Fourier Transform?

Tags: fourier-transform, bessel-functions, correlation

I came across an integral that is the Fourier transform of the nth power of a surface roughness correlation function (with correlation length zeta). I am wondering why does this integral contains a Bessel function and what is the intuitive meaning of this?
$$
W^n(K) = \int_0^\infty \rho^n(\xi) J_0(K\xi) \xi \, d\xi
$$

Comment: In what sense is the integral a _Fourier_ transform of something? It seems more like a Bessel transform.

Comment: So it is an eigenfunction expansion of a problem that naturally involves Bessel functions. This is common in modeling problems involving the 2D Laplacian.

Comment: So basically if we consider it just an integral the zeroth order Bessel function should be replaced by "Sin(x)/x", where x=k*zeta.